# Why didn't Tar-Míriel leave with the faithful?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

I mean surely she was still in contact with them; after all, she was faithful herself, wasn't she? Also there was a lot of time between Ar-Pharazôn's Great Fleet and the Downfall of Númenor: approximately 36 days I believe it was. Yet she chose not to join them on the ships and tried to reach the top of Meneltarma (which was on fire at the time of the downfall). So why didn't she meet up with Elendil and the rest of her kinsmen?

Comment: The Kingsmen probably stopped her from leaving since she was the wife of their King.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unknown

The most plausible explanation is that forces loyal to Sauron prevented her; we know that they tried to prevent Elendil from leaving:

> Elendil had remained in Romenna, refusing the summons of the King when he set forth to war; and avoiding the soldiers of Sauron that came to seize him and drag him to the fires of the Temple, he went aboard his ship and stood off from the shore, waiting on the time.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* IV *Akallabêth*</sup>

Even if we suppose that Míriel *was* in contact with the Faithful, it would presumably have been difficult for her to leave the Palace to join them, especially since (given who her father was) she was almost certainly suspected of having sympathies with enemies of the state.

Finally, I'll point out that Tolkien's later writings cast doubt on the assumption that Míriel's loyalties were with the Faithful; some late scribbles introduce the idea that Míriel actually *did* love Ar-Pharazôn, in which case she presumably stayed behind for personal reasons. Christopher Tolkien comments:

> It is not perfectly clear to me how the textual puzzle presented by these writings is to be resolved, but I am inclined to think that, contrary to appearance, the texts (a), (b), and (c) in fact followed the writing of the long rider to the Akallabêth, and that they represent the emergence of a doubt in my father's mind whether the marriage of Pharazôn and Zimrahil was indeed 'against her will', and the sketching of a new story on the subject.
>
> <sup>*History of Middle-earth* XII *The Peoples of Middle-earth* Part One Chapter 5: "The History of the Akallabêth"</sup>

Comment: Speculative - she may have been required to exercise governmental authority in the absence of the King; from this obligation she could not have held herself excused to join a (from a strictly legal point of view) separatist group.

Answer (score 2):

Remembering that Tar-Míriel was the Queen and therefore (notionally) in charge of affairs in Númenor, she probably felt that it was her duty to stay in Armenelos even if in her heart she wanted to leave. Her thought was probably; "The Queen does not desert her people."

Comment: But if she was a faithful Numenorean then her people would of been the Elendili and not the Kingsmen who several centuries prior to the Great Armament turned away from the teachings of Elves and the Valar while the faithful remained loyal to the powers in the West and during Ar-Pharazon's (Usurped) reign they turned toward evil and chaos worshipping Morgoth as per the advice of Sauron (who wanted the Numenoreans destroyed) and thus would have created a stronger pull towards leaving Numenor with Elendil and the rest of the faithful Numenoreans to Middle earth.